# Error : vb selectsinglenode object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-config, xmldocument

Am getting error object variable or with block variable not set while SelectSingleNode from xml document

Here is my code

```
 sWC = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\inetpub\" & sServer & "\web.config")
    Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load("c:\inetpub\" & sServer & "\web.config")

  Dim nodeRegion = xmlDoc.CreateElement("add")
        nodeRegion.SetAttribute("key", sAppPool)
        nodeRegion.SetAttribute("value", "Sunday,12:00 AM")
        xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings").AppendChild(nodeRegion)
        xmlDoc.Save("c:\inetpub\" & sServer & "\web.config")
```

`xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings")` in this am getting `"Nothing"` as string

In my web.config i have

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

xmlns in configuration section .

If i removed from "xmlns" from configuration tag i am able to update my web.config .
if i kept this am getting object variable or with block variable not set error while `SelectSingleNode` from xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace (namespace declared without prefix). Descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace implicitly, unless otherwise specified. To access element in namespace, you need to map a prefix to point to the namespace uri, and then use that prefix in your XPath :

```
Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load("c:\inetpub\" & sServer & "\web.config")
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0")
......
......
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//d:appSettings", nsmgr).AppendChild(nodeRegion)
xmlDoc.Save("c:\inetpub\" & sServer & "\web.config")
```

Comment: But it is adding extra xmlns="" in appsettings

Comment: Try to create the new element using the default namespace uri : `Dim nodeRegion = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "add", 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0")`. Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c22k3d47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't declared your `//appSettings` Section. Could you post your XML-File? Try adding `<appSettings> [.. Your Implementation here ..]</appSettings>` to it! ;)

** **EDIT** **

I've got the same issue some time ago. This is the Code I am using in Visual C++ right now. The UpdateAppSettings is called with two arrays, one is containing the key names and the other is containing the corresponding value. So lets say in you call this function like:

```
UpdateAppSettings(gcnew array<String^>{"key"},gcnew array<String^>{"value"});
```

... it will write the following into your .config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key" value="value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Maybe something like this is exactly what you intent to do?

```
static void Daten::UpdateAppSetting(array<String^>^ names, array<String^>^ newVal) {
            System::Configuration::ExeConfigurationFileMap^ ConfigMap =
                     gcnew System::Configuration::ExeConfigurationFileMap();

            // Here you declare what file ConfigMap should refer to
            ConfigMap->ExeConfigFilename = "C:\\{YOURAPPLICATIONNAME}.config";
            // .config file einlesen und Daten in config speichern
            MyConfig = 
                      System::Configuration::ConfigurationManager::OpenMappedExeConfiguration(ConfigMap, ConfigurationUserLevel::None);


            for (int i = 0; i < names->Length; i++) {

                    if (MyConfig->AppSettings->Settings[names[i]] != (nullptr))
                        MyConfig->AppSettings->Settings->Remove(names[i]);

                MyConfig->AppSettings->Settings->Add(names[i], newVal[i]);
            }
            MyConfig->Save(ConfigurationSaveMode::Modified);
            ConfigurationManager::RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }
```

Comment: I added appSettings tag in my web.config Please check my edit in my question <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=session;timeout=20;" />-->
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;" />
    <add key="UseCache" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: So, if you added the <appSettings> into your XML, try to leave away `//`. So it looks like `xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("appSettings");`.

Although this is not the corrent way to use an XML File. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 for some more information on how to use XmlDocument.

Comment: No same issue even after removing // form node .

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms162365(v=vs.110).aspx

May I ask what your scope is? Just curious because you are using the prefix `appSettings`. Normally I'd recommend you to use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms134269(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Am trying to add and update appsettings in web.config  Leon

Comment: Thank you Leon .har07 posted answer to my question which is working well fro me.